# How to install python packages to embedded python in GDB/ clion2017.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdb, pip, clion

I'm using CLion 2017.1 and GDB for debugging. GDB compiled with python 2.7 support, but with no modules.

I wish to use `matplotlib` in order to plot some debug data (using [GDB image watch](https://github.com/cuekoo/GDB-ImageWatch)) but there is no `matplotlib` presence. and no `pip` to install it.

I've tried to install `pip` using `(gdb) python import get_pip` but

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/temp/get_pip.py", line 28, in     <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/home/user/clion-2016.3.4/bin/gdb/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/home/user/clion-2016.3.4/bin/gdb/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 48, in <module>
    from binascii import hexlify as _hexlify
ImportError: No module named binascii
Error while executing Python code.
```

So I don't know how to bootstrap instullation of additional modules into GDB's embedded python.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Try using GDB installed on your system (`/usr/bin/gdb` or so) instead of the bundled one. Does it help?

Comment: Does `python setup.py` not work?

Answer (score -1):

> I've tried to install pip using (gdb) python import get_pip but

You need not install python modules from gdb shell. You can install them from command line as usual with your package manager or with pip. Make sure that you installed Python2 version of module. Once the module is installed you can use it in gdb embedded python:

```
$ gdb -q
(gdb) python
>import matplotlib
>end
(gdb)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have the same issue. I have python installed with matplotlib. I can use it in my python scripts. But not inside gdb: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Comment: It could be Python2/Python3 mismatch. Try to install both Python2 and Python3 versions of matplotlib module.

Comment: My gdb (sys.version) says that it uses Python 3.6.3: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] I have both python 2 and python 3 installed, both with matplotlib. But My python3 is 64 bit. Maybe here is the problem. I'll install python 3 32bit and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help also. Still the same error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Comment: I'm on linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), and have the same issue.